# spark cannot read nested JSON properly from the folder path, but can read the data if I specify the exact file path

Tags: json, pyspark

I need to read some files stored in blob in pyspark.

file_path = "/mnt/.../FileFormat=json/SchemaId=v0/

Within in the folder, files are saved per ingestion date.
I am trying to read last 7 days files like this -

df_raw = spark.read.json(file_path).filter(
F.col("IngestionDate") > F.expr("current_date() - interval 7 days")
)

Everything was working fine but recently we found out that for one particular record, some of the fields are read as Null.

When I specified the whole path of the file like

file_path = "/mnt/.../FileFormat=json/SchemaId=v0/Type=full/IngestionDate=2023-11-08/IngestionTimestamp=2023-11-08T13:30:03+00:00/file.json"

It can read the whole data. I tried giving till IngestionDate, that also worked.
Here I need to consider last 7 days files.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Can you add a picture